# Trying to deserialize list of ints using DataContractSerializer, received unexpected InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, xml, datacontractserializer

Expectation: Read the list of ints from the XML-file to the List called itemPool;

Result: "InvalidOperationException: Failed to add type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] to known type collection. There already is a registered type for XML name http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays:ArrayOfint"

I have to following code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

using Characters;
using Items;

[DataContract(Name ="Savefile", Namespace ="")]
public class Savefile
{
    [DataMember(Name ="Characters")]
    public List<Character> characters = new List<Character>();

    [DataMember(Name = "ItemPool")]
    public List<int> itemPool = new List<int>();

    public void Initialize()
    {
        foreach (Character c in characters)
            c.Initialize();

        ItemPool.Load(itemPool.ToArray());
    }
}
```

And another class with the following method:

```
    public static void LoadFromSavefile()
    {
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Savefile));
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, _savefilePath), FileMode.Open);

        _currentSave = serializer.ReadObject(stream) as Savefile;

        stream.Close();
    }
```

And the following xml-file that the class above reads from.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Savefile xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Characters>
    <Character>
      <... not relevant clutter.../>
    </Character>
  </Characters>
  <ItemPool>
    <value>1</value>
  </ItemPool>
</Savefile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited using DataContractSerializer.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace UnitTestProject1 {

    [DataContract(Name = "Savefile", Namespace = "")]
    public class Savefile {
        [DataMember(Name = "Characters", Order = 0)]
        public Characters Characters { get; private set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "ItemPool", Order = 1)]
        public Items ItemPool { get; private set; }

    }

    [CollectionDataContract(Name = "Characters", ItemName = "Character", Namespace = "")]
    public class Characters : List<Character> {

    }

    public class Character {
        public string Weapon { get; set; }
        internal void Initialize() {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    [CollectionDataContract(Name = "ItemPool", ItemName = "Item", Namespace = "")]
    public class Items : List<int> {
        public int value { get; set; }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTestSerialization {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1() {
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Savefile));
            FileStream stream = new FileStream("SaveFile2.xml", FileMode.Open);
            XmlDictionaryReader reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(stream, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());

            Savefile _currentSave = (Savefile)serializer.ReadObject(reader);
            Assert.IsNotNull(_currentSave);


            stream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Savefile>
  <Characters>
    <Character>
      <Weapon>Axe</Weapon>
    </Character>
    <Character>
      <Weapon>Mace</Weapon>
    </Character>
    <Character>

    </Character>
  </Characters>
  <ItemPool>
    <Item>1</Item>
    <Item>2</Item>
  </ItemPool>
</Savefile>
```

Comment: I'm using DataContractSerializer so I can serialize private fields - using public fields for everything that needs to be serialized isn't really feasible.

I might've been vague in my op, the Item class does not have a field called "value", that's just the XML definition of an array of ints, as far as I know.


int[] ints { 1 } = 
<ints>
<value>1</value>
</ints>

Comment: I have edited the file to use DataContractSerializer

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding my issue/question, I am not deserializing a list of items - I'm trying to deserialize a list of ints.

And for some reason I receive the InvalidOperationException.

Comment: list of ints is what Items property are. public class Items :List<int>; correct? If you replace ItemName="Item" with ItemName="value" it will match your xml correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry, I read your code wrong at first, this works. 
Do you have any idea what might have caused my error in the initial code?

Comment: @ag4w since it is a knownType error, it may have to do with that, known type collection. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/collection-types-in-data-contracts

Comment: @ag4w CollectionDataContract is required